Uniqueness of the restriction of a measure on the trace $Y \cap \mathcal{A}$
Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, let $Y \in \mathcal{A}$, and let $\mu: \mathcal{A} \to [0, \infty]$ be a measure. Show that:
The restriction $\mu|_{Y \cap \mathcal{A}}$ is unique and is a measure on $Y \cap \mathcal{A}$.
I already showed that $\mu$ restricted on $Y \cap \mathcal{A}$ is a measure. However, I am struggling to prove the uniqueness of such a restriction. Could anybody help me?

What do you mean by "uniquely defined"?

I edited my post. It just means that the restriction is unique.

A restriction of a map to a subset is always unique, isn't it?
